# how to transform old rspec-syntax "it { should_not be_valid }" to rspec2?

Tags: rspec, rspec2

transform from old rspec syntax to the new one:

old:

```
 describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

How should the it-part looks like with the newer expect-syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the expect-syntax the test would be:

```
it { is_expected.not_to be_valid }
```

Note that for the one-liner syntax, the should-syntax is still supported (ie no deprecation warning) so you do not have to make any changes. From the [Relish page on RSpec Core 3.1](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax):

> - `is_expected` is defined simply as expect(subject) and is designed for when you are using rspec-expectations with its newer expect-based
>     syntax.
> - `should` was designed back when rspec-expectations only had a should-based syntax. However, it continues to be available and work
>     even if the `:should` syntax is disabled (since that merely removes
>     Object#should but this is RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup#should).